# Should I pursue math or physics as a career?

Tags: student-motivation

If I studied laplace transforms, fourier analysis, multivariable calculus, differential equations, partial differential equations by 9th grade, does that mean I have talent for math or for physics. Most of the topics I studied are applied mathematics meaning they are mostly applied in the sciences.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't been exposed to enough of either mathematics or physics to decide your preference. I recommend: Pursue both in parallel until your inclinations become clear. Perhaps *mathematical physics* will become your natural home...?

Comment: I'm new to this community (I mostly live on [cseducators.SE]), but are career advice questions really on-topic here?

Comment: @BenI. I would say 'yes, careers advice questions are off topic'. But whether they are or not, this is too personal to be on topic.